# Ctypes: Why WinDLL(library) doesn't work and WinDLL(find_library(library)) does?

Tags: python, ctypes, python-3.11

I'm working with an external wrapper that loads a dll in python. They use the below:

```
from ctypes import *
_lib = WinDLL(library)
```

However, I'm getting the error:

*FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'vcmowr64' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.*

The dll is in the same directory as all the python files being used. The odd thing is that if I use the below, the code works:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library

_lib = WinDLL(find_library(library))
```

I don't understand why. I imagined that find_library function had same logic to find the dll as the WinDLL.

I'm using Windows 11 Enterprise and python 3.11.

Comment: Check what `find_library(library)` returns for a hint.

Comment: It returns the relative path, but in theory the WinDLL should work with names or path. Is not clear why the find_library can find the dll and not the WinDLL.

Comment: Use `WinDLL('./library')` to explicitly look in the current directory or use the full path. It doesn’t look in the current directory by default.